# PyQt5, I need not to print continuously but instead it only changes the QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5

I need it to be not continuously printing but instead it only change the QLabel, 
I dont need to add more, just whenever you write in Line edit it should replace the existing text. I need it like a stocks

This is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        self.game_name = QLabel("Stocks:", self)

        self.game_line_edit = QLineEdit(self)

        self.search_button = QPushButton("Print", self)

        self.search_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.hbox.addWidget(self.game_name)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.game_line_edit)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.search_button)

        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        game = QLabel(self.game_line_edit.text(), self)
        self.hbox.addWidget(game)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `QLabel`, set it in the layout and only update the text with `setText()`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.game_name = QLabel("Stocks:")
        self.game_line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.search_button = QPushButton("Print")
        self.search_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.game = QLabel()

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)        
        hbox.addWidget(self.game_name)
        hbox.addWidget(self.game_line_edit)
        hbox.addWidget(self.search_button)
        hbox.addWidget(self.game)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        self.game.setText(self.game_line_edit.text())

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @ellyanesc how can i add a clear button? and also i dont know how I will add a button that create a copy of the whole thing and paste it underneath so I can add some more items and stocks.

Comment: @Lance You should try something, when we are in the learning process we usually do not know how to do it then we use tutorials, old OS questions to gain experience. Do not expect the OS community to do their work

Comment: I'm very new in pyqt5, so i dont know how to do my deadline would be monday thanks I will

Comment: @Lance Well, in SO there are already rules about homework, it is understood that the task is for you to learn and it is considered dishonest to ask others to do it for you.

Comment: no I have reason for it, my teacher don't taught this, and he want us to be perfectly submitted on his deadline me and my all classmates are having difficulty answering.

Comment: @Lance Well, your tutor has the responsibility to teach you, how do you ask for something that I do not teach ?, so it is your responsibility to demand information since the job of your tutor is to help you. Goodbye